# Determine if action was executed in functions

Tags: customization

I've got the following code:

```
add_filter('media_row_actions','delete_link', 2, 1);
function delete_link( $wp_query_obj ) {
    echo "it is in this one";
    //if( !current_user_can( 'delete_plugins' ) ){
        unset($wp_query_obj['delete']);
        return $wp_query_obj;
    //}
}
```

I'm trying to determine if the hook is actually executed so I printed out an echo just to see if some text is returned. I don't see the text so I don't think it was executed but don't know for sure. If I look at the trac for that function at the following URL:
`https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-media-list-table.php#L551`

The hook is:

```
$actions = apply_filters( 'media_row_actions', $actions, $post, $this->detached );
```

I also tried to make the hook be:

```
add_action('media_row_actions','delete_link', 2, 1);
```

I still didn't see the echo when I did this. I'm just displaying the Media page and clicking on the images to display the attachment details. I want to eventually do a `print_r($wp_query_obj)` so I know what is in the object and see what actions I can unset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`media_row_actions` only filters the links in the Media Library (/wp-admin/upload.php?mode=list)

And `$wp_query_obj` really should be `$actions`, since that's whats being filtered.

What's in the object is an array of action keys and corresponding action links:

```
(
    [edit] => <a href="http://domain.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=XX&amp;action=edit">Edit</a>
    [delete] => <a class='submitdelete' onclick='return showNotice.warn();' href='post.php?action=delete&amp;post=XX&amp;_wpnonce=XXXX'>Delete Permanently</a>
    [view] => <a href="http://domain.com/?attachment_id=XX" title="View &#8220;Attachment Title&#8221;" rel="permalink">View</a>
)
```

Comment: I see what you mean now. I was hoping to do this in the Attachment details when the image is clicked. Thanks for pointing this out.